# Passing a function(with parameters) to JSON service in Metro Apps?

Tags: web-services, html, microsoft-metro, winjs

I have a metro application using HTML and Winjs, in which am trying to call a service which gives output in JSON format. But the service takes functions name(with parameters) as input.
I know how to call a service with general url but don't know how to send function name with that url.

Comment: it would be up to the service owner to tell you what they are expecting and how - is it a public service you could share the details for?  It could be RESTful with the arguments as part of the URI itself, or maybe it expects a query string, or a POSTed form, or even a SOAP envelope and message.

Comment: Thank you @Jim,My service is a SOAP envelope.Can you give me some helpful information

Comment: ugh, well you'll have to create the SOAP payload and provide that as the HTTP request body - take a look at http://openlandscape.net/2009/09/25/call-soap-xm-web-services-with-jquery-ajax/ for starters